# Russian prepositions & stress

Tags: грамматика, ударение

Because prepositions act like clitics, they are pronounced as if the're part of the next word.Does that mean the vowels of the prepositions are also reduced to [ə] and [ɐ] and does this also apply to conjunctions?

So are these examples pronounced correctly?

на столе [nə] [stɐˈlʲe]
на почте [nɐ] [ˈpot͡ɕtʲe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct; reduction applies to prepositions as if they were part of the next word, and there's even a limited number of preposition-noun combinations where the preposition steals stress: **пóд ноги** (but: под ногáми), **нá руку** (but: **на рукé**).

(I have to correct what I originally wrote after this, and double-checking is welcome.)

It does not apply to conjunctions. **Но** is always [nо]; **а** is always [a]; **что** is always [ʂto], etc. However, in colloquial speech, the compound conjunctions `то, что`, `то, чтобы` and `то, как` and their oblique forms can be pronounced as one word, with stress on the first element: ['toʂtə], ['toʂtəbɨ], ['tokək]. **Потому что** without the comma is always pronounced as one word.